# Regular Expressions Python - Plotting data out of text file

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get some data out of text file with the following format:

```
jvm: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    MemoryStatistics: [290328680, 381288448]

moniData: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    Depth: [0]
    RecordsSent: [1]

rdoutData: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    Depth: [0]
    RecordsSent: [0]

rdoutReq: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    TotalRecordsReceived: 132
    RecordsReceived: [132]
    BytesReceived: [8184]

sender: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    NumReadoutRequestsReceived: 178
    NumHitsReceived: 2663
    NumReadoutsSent: 1
    NumHitsCached: 0
    NumHitsQueued: 310
    NumReadoutRequestsQueued: 0

snData: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    Depth: [0]
    RecordsSent: [61]

stringHit: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    Depth: [8]
    RecordsSent: [3026]

stringhub: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    TimeOfLastHitOutputFromHKN1: 207977962295545677
    NumberOfActiveAndTotalChannels: [60, 60]
    NumberOfActiveChannels: 60
    TimeOfLastHitInputToHKN1: 207977964479700660
    HitRateLC: 0.0
    HitRate: 0.0
    TotalLBMOverflows: 1091

system: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    LoadAverage: [0.0, 0.02, 0.35999999999999999]
    NetworkIO: {'lo_tx_errs': 0, 'eth1_rx_fifo': 0, 'eth2_rx_packets': 0, 'eth1_tx_compressed': 0, 'eth2_tx_compressed': 0, 'eth0_tx_fifo': 0, 'eth1_tx_packets': 0, 'lo_tx_compressed': 0, 'eth1_rx_compressed': 0, 'lo_rx_errs': 0, 'eth1_tx_fifo': 0, 'lo_tx_fifo': 0, 'eth0_tx_errs': 0, 'eth0_rx_multicast': 0, 'eth0_tx_carrier': 0, 'eth3_rx_compressed': 0, 'eth3_tx_drop': 0, 'lo_tx_drop': 0, 'eth2_rx_drop': 0, 'eth1_tx_drop': 0, 'eth3_rx_bytes': 0, 'eth3_tx_packets': 0, 'lo_rx_bytes': 8270472, 'eth2_rx_errs': 0, 'eth3_tx_errs': 0, 'eth0_rx_errs': 0, 'eth2_tx_errs': 0, 'lo_rx_packets': 71359, 'eth2_rx_compressed': 0, 'eth3_rx_packets': 0, 'eth0_tx_drop': 0, 'eth0_rx_frame': 0, 'eth1_tx_bytes': 0, 'eth1_rx_multicast': 0, 'eth1_rx_packets': 0, 'eth2_tx_fifo': 0, 'eth1_tx_errs': 0, 'eth2_tx_bytes': 0, 'eth3_rx_frame': 0, 'eth2_rx_frame': 0, 'eth1_rx_bytes': 0, 'eth0_rx_drop': 0, 'eth3_rx_drop': 0, 'eth1_rx_frame': 0, 'eth2_tx_packets': 0, 'eth0_tx_bytes': 389183382674, 'eth3_rx_errs': 0, 'eth0_rx_bytes': 141781372747, 'eth3_tx_compressed': 0, 'eth2_rx_fifo': 0, 'lo_tx_bytes': 8270472, 'eth1_rx_errs': 0, 'eth1_tx_carrier': 0, 'eth0_rx_packets': 478007025, 'lo_rx_drop': 0, 'eth0_tx_compressed': 0, 'eth0_rx_fifo': 0, 'eth3_tx_colls': 0, 'eth0_tx_colls': 0, 'lo_tx_packets': 71359, 'eth2_rx_multicast': 0, 'eth2_tx_colls': 0, 'eth3_tx_fifo': 0, 'eth1_tx_colls': 0, 'lo_tx_carrier': 0, 'lo_rx_frame': 0, 'eth1_rx_drop': 0, 'lo_tx_colls': 0, 'eth3_tx_bytes': 0, 'lo_rx_fifo': 0, 'eth2_tx_drop': 0, 'eth3_tx_carrier': 0, 'eth3_rx_multicast': 0, 'eth0_rx_compressed': 0, 'eth2_rx_bytes': 0, 'eth2_tx_carrier': 0, 'eth0_tx_packets': 1197286889, 'lo_rx_multicast': 0, 'lo_rx_compressed': 0, 'eth3_rx_fifo': 0}
    AvailableDiskSpace: {'/': 43836096, '/dev/shm': 24725760}

tcalData: 2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864:
    Depth: [0]
    RecordsSent: [0]

PyrateBufferManager: 2011-08-29 17:09:57.031479:
    CurrentAquiredBuffers: 0
    ReturnBufferCount: 4285
    CurrentAquiredBytes: 0
```

I am trying to get a plot that is time versus the various quantities stored in the file, so basically I would like to get out a couple arrays that are similar to this format:

```
timestamp=[...,17:09:54.438864,...]
snDataDepth=[..,0,...]
snDataRecordsSend=[..., 61,...]
```

I got recommendations by other people to use something like

```
f = open(file, "r").readlines()
dummy=[]
for i in f:
    dummy.append(i.split("[")[1].split("]")[0])
```

to get the numbers our. I am having trouble getting the data sorted properly using the categories in the text (see above) and the timestamp.

Thanks in advance for any help

As requested:

Already used that to get some other data out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, re
import numpy as np
import pylab as py

def main():
    snrate=[]
    PyrateBufferManagerCABu=[]
    PyrateBufferManagerRBC=[]
    PyrateBufferManagerCABy=[]
    end=".moni;.log"
    for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)):
        file = os.path.splitext(sys.argv[i])[0]
        ext = os.path.splitext(sys.argv[i])[1]
        print file
        if 'log' in ext:
            f=open(sys.argv[i], 'rU')
            dummy=[]
            dummy1=[]
            for line in f:
                dummy += re.findall('snRate: (\d.?\d+)', line)
                dummy1 += re.findall('Buffer overflow in SN record channel:', line)
            snrate.append(dummy)
            print ext
        if 'moni' in ext:
            f=open(sys.argv[i], 'rU').readlines()
            #print f
            timestamp=[]
            dummy=[]
            count=0
            for line in f:
                timestamp += re.findall(r'\d\d:\S+:\d\d.\d\d',line)
                if 'PyrateBufferManager' in line:
                    PyrateBufferManagerCABu += re.findall(r'\S+-\S+-(CurrentAquiredBuffers)\:\s\d+', line[count+1])
                    print PyrateBufferManagerCABu
                    PyrateBufferManagerRBC += re.findall(r'ReturnBufferCount:\s\S+',line[count+2])
                    PyrateBufferManagerCABy += re.findall(r'CurrentAquiredBytes:\s\S+', line[count+3])
            timestamp=list(set(timestamp))
            timestamp.sort()
            print PyrateBufferManagerCABu, PyrateBufferManagerRBC
            print ext
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's builtin lib re for regular expressions.
To get all of the timestamps you can do something like this:

```
import re

def main():
    file=open(file)
    timestamp=(re.findall(r'\S+-\S+-\d\d\s\d\d:\S+:\S+:',file.read()))
    print timestamp

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Already used that to get some other data out:

    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys, os, re
    import numpy as np
    import pylab as py
    snrate=[]
    for i in range(1,len(sys.argv)):
        print i
        f=open(sys.argv[i], 'rU')
        dummy=[]
        dummy1=[]
        if f:
            for line in f:
                dummy += re.findall('snRate: (\d.?\d+)', line)
                dummy1 += re.findall('Buffer overflow in SN record channel:', line)
                print len(dummy)
                print len(dummy1)
                snrate.append(dummy)

Comment: @madtowneast I find it ironic that it is impossible to post a legal Python program in the comment field here due to the whitespace inanity.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse your input data using [`lepl`](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ast
import fileinput
import logging

from datetime import datetime
from pprint   import pprint
from string   import ascii_letters, digits

from lepl import Any, Iterate, Newline, Regexp, SkipTo, Space

# ABNF: property = name colon python_literal
name = Any(ascii_letters+digits)[1:,...] # \w+
colon = Space()[:,...] & ':' & Space()[:,...] # \s*:\s*
python_literal = Regexp(r'.+') >> ast.literal_eval
property_ = name & ~colon & python_literal > tuple

# record consists of name, timestamp and one or more properties
#   ABNF: record = name colon timestamp colon 1*( NEWLINE indent property )
timestamp = Regexp(r'.*[^\s:]') >> (lambda s: (
    datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")))
record = (name & ~colon & timestamp & ~colon &
          ((~Newline() & ~Space()[1:,...] & property_)[1:] > dict)) > tuple

# file consists of one or more records interlaced with newlines
#   ABNF: file = 1*( NEWLINE | record )
#     skip unrecognized text upto new line 
unknown = SkipTo(Newline()) > (lambda s: logging.error('unknown: %r' % (s,)))
it = Iterate(record | ~Newline() | ~unknown) # consume input one record at a time
it.config.no_full_first_match().no_memoize() # improve performance

iterparse = it.get_parse_file_all() # output one record at a time
pprint([lst[0] for lst in iterparse(fileinput.input()) if lst])
```

#### Output

```
[('jvm',
  datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 29, 17, 9, 54, 438864),
  {'MemoryStatistics': [290328680, 381288448]}),
 ('moniData',
  datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 29, 17, 9, 54, 438864),
  {'Depth': [0], 'RecordsSent': [1]}),
 ('rdoutData',
  datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 29, 17, 9, 54, 438864),
  {'Depth': [0], 'RecordsSent': [0]}),
 ('rdoutReq',
  datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 29, 17, 9, 54, 438864),
  {'BytesReceived': [8184],
   'RecordsReceived': [132],
   'TotalRecordsReceived': 132}),
 ('sender',
  datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 29, 17, 9, 54, 438864),
  {'NumHitsCached': 0,
   'NumHitsQueued': 310,
   'NumHitsReceived': 2663,
   'NumReadoutRequestsQueued': 0,
   'NumReadoutRequestsReceived': 178,
   'NumReadoutsSent': 1}),
 ('snData',
  datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 29, 17, 9, 54, 438864),
  {'Depth': [0], 'RecordsSent': [61]}),
 # ... snip ...
 ('PyrateBufferManager',
  datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 29, 17, 9, 57, 31479),
  {'CurrentAquiredBuffers': 0,
   'CurrentAquiredBytes': 0,
   'ReturnBufferCount': 4285})]
```

Comment: That looks really good. I have a question though what is the out? I see a lot of tuples, lists within a list? Wouldnt a dictionary within a dictionary work too?

Comment: @madtowneast: yes. `dict` works too (group a record into 2-item tuple: I don't know what you prefer: `(name, timestamp), properties` or `name, (timestamp, properties)`). You could use `collections.OrderedDict()` to preserve records order (the same goes for properties).

Comment: I was thinking about {timestamp: {name: {properties:}}} I will try adjust your code that way.

Comment: Would it just be `s=open(file, 'rU').readlines()`? Just getting confused about to go through the file.

Comment: @madtowneast: use [`.parse_file()`](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/faq.html?highlight=parse_file#faq-file)

Comment: @madtowneast: to convert to `{{{` format replace `tuple` for the `record` matcher by your function that accepts: `[name, timestamp, properties dict]` list and returns your desirable format.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3309/discussion-between-j-f-sebastian-and-madtowneast)

Answer (score 1):

Why not simplicity ? :

```
import re

regx = re.compile('snData: +(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d +\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d+).+'
                  'Depth: +\[(\d+)\].+'
                  'RecordsSent: +\[(\d+)\]', re.DOTALL)

timestamp, snDataDepth, snDataRecordsSend = [], [], []

with open('data_for_plot.txt') as f:
    ch = f.read()

a,b,c = regx.search(ch).groups()

timestamp.append(a)
snDataDepth.append(b)
snDataRecordsSend.append(c)

print timestamp
print snDataDepth
print snDataRecordsSend
```

result

```
['2011-08-29 17:09:54.438864']
['0']
['0']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`yaml`](http://yaml.org/) to parse your file if you transform it slightly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import datetime
import re

import yaml

text = open('input').read()

# transform text to make it a valid yaml
re_name = re.compile(r'^(\w+\:)\s', re.MULTILINE)
yaml_text = re.sub(re_name, r'\1\n ', text)

#
obj = yaml.load(yaml_text)
d = obj['sender'][datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 29, 17, 9, 54, 438864)]
print('number of hits: {NumHitsQueued}'.format(**d))
```

#### Output

```
number of hits: 310
```